# How to separate a list of indices and data points

Tags: import

If I copy and paste a list of data points from the OEIS the indices come with the data points.  Mathematica seems to view this as a product 0 times 0 times 1 times 0 times 2 times ... times 51.  I want to use the data points but not the indices.  Is there a way to get rid of the indices in this list.  For example

0 0
1 0
2 1
3 0
4 1
5 1
6 3
7 4
8 11
9 20
10 51

I want the sequence {0,0,1,0,1,1,3,4,11,20,51}.  In other words, I want every other term in what I copied and pasted from OEIS.

Comment: Have you tried `First[ImportString["0 0 1 0 2 1 3 0 4 1 5 1 6 3 7 4 8 11 9 20 10 51", "Table"]][[2 ;; -1 ;; 2]]` already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods, but perhaps the best might be, for example:

```
A = Select[Import["https://oeis.org/A000677/b000677.txt", "Table"], 
    Length@# == 2 &][[All, 2]];
A[[1 ;; 11]]
(* {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 11, 20, 51} *)
```

One advantage is that this can be automated because it avoids
the manual copy and paste step.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you have the sequence a s a string, you may read the string by:

```
str = "0 0 1 0 2 1 3 0 4 1 5 1 6 3 7 4 8 11 9 20 10 51";
dat = ReadList[StringToStream[str], Number]

(*{0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8, 11, 9, 20, 10, 51} *)
```

To get every second element you may write:

```
 dat = dat[[2 ;; ;; 2]]

(* {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 11, 20, 51} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Doubtless I would do this

```
str = "0 0 1 0 2 1 3 0 4 1 5 1 6 3 7 4 8 11 9 20 10 51";
ToExpression[Last /@ Partition[StringSplit[str], 2]]
```

> {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 11, 20, 51}

Comment: Note that this evaluates to a list of `String`, not a list of `Integer`.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Indeed, thanks - I have now added ToExpression.